# Can't access server from external IP

Tags: iis, iis-7, port-forwarding

I have a problem with my web server;
I can't access it from the external IP address. I'm using an IIS 7 server, but I've tried with apache on Linux as well. I have forwarded all traffic on port 80 to my computer, but it just won't work. I've done port forwarding with my Minecraft server, and it did work, but when I try it with a web server, no. I've been looking on many many forums, but their methods don't work for me. My router is a Speedport W 723V, if anyone knows that one. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you in a residence? Many ISP's will block ingoing traffic to port 80 if you're on a non-commercial plan.

Comment: I have port 80 as preset as web server so I don't think it's blocked.

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple problems, to determine whether it is a router or a server problem, you could test your port-forwarding here http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/